On facebook if making an anonymous post, is it possible to get a link to the post to see if there has been a reply?
On facebook if making an anonymous post in a group, is it possible to get a link to the post to see if there has been a reply?
for example when making an anonymous post it says it has been submitted to be reviewed by moderation.
but no link is given.

This comment should either be an answer to the question or an [edit] to the question (if it's providing additional details). I'm a bit confused but could you do one or the other to help others that find the post?

If the post doesn't go through moderation then the post would appear immediately.. some groups a post / anonymous post won't need moderation.. and then it will appear straight away, then you can get a link to it. You do get a notification if somebody reacts to your anonymous post so you'd get a notification if it got a repl
